# What is the trajectory of a particle under a constant angular force always perpendicular to its position vector?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, classical-mechanics, coordinate-systems

It is a question of classical mechanics, related but indeed distinguished from the central force problem.

> The equation of motion can be expressed as below in polar coordinates:
>   $$\ddot{r}-r\dot{\theta}^2=0 \\ r\ddot{\theta}+2\dot{r}\dot{\theta}=\frac{F}{m}$$
>   with initial condition of zero velocity (whatever, just for simplification):
>   $$r(0)=r_0,\ \theta(0)=0,\ \dot{r}(0)=0,\ \dot{\theta}(0)=0.$$

However, I am not talent to analytically solve this equation. 
Can you help me?

Of course, the famous first integral in central force problem, the angular momentum, dose not help to solve it. I believe that the trajectory has a name, I mean some meaningful curve, but I cannot find it.

Also I am curious that can this problem map to any real physical system? It might help to solve it.

Comment: You can solve it numerically if you want an idea of what the curve looks like and don't know how to solve it exactly

Comment: Do you mean perpendicular to its velocity vector?

Comment: @Farcher Nope. That question is a routine exercise. This one is a difficult system of differential equations. It has nothing to do with uniform circular motion.

Comment: @Naptzer Thank you for your comment. Of course I know how to solve it numerically, and indeed I have done it.

Comment: From the numerical calculation, I just know the radius (r) increases very fast. It actually helps nothing, and I think a handwriting curve is enough for knowing the shape of the trajectory.

Answer (score 1):

This definitely corresponds to a physical system: consider a mass inside a frictionless semi-infinite tube with one end at the origin. Your situation corresponds to rotating the tube so that the normal force on the mass is constant. From this setup it's intuitively clear that this tends to force the mass away from the origin.

I've encountered this setup before, but with a constant torque, which would probably be the more realistic case. In that case it's easy to solve because the angular momentum increases linearly in time. Your case is harder. After eliminating $\theta$ I arrived at
$$3 \dot{r} \ddot{r} + r \dddot{r} = (r \ddot{r})^{1/2} \frac{F}{m}$$
from which we can observe that one solution is
$$r(t) = \frac{F}{6 \sqrt{2} m} \, t^2$$
which also implies that $\theta(t) \propto \log t$. But I don't know how to solve it for general initial conditions.

I don't have time to pursue this further, but one technique you may want to try is complexification. That is, represent the position of the particle in the $xy$ plane as a complex number $z$. Then you only have one equation, $\ddot{z} \propto i z/|z|$, which is rather simple. Hopefully somebody can finish this analysis!

Comment: So is this asking about the trajectory of a particle in a centrifuge?

Comment: @Farcher Yes, but one which exerts constant force instead of constant torque, which is a bit strange.

Comment: Thank you for yout quick response! Somehow when I try to sovle it, I try to avoid increasing the order of this differental equation, because the initial condition is just of first order. Do you think it is must that to kown the second order initial condiction?

Comment: @qfzklm I was just trying to get rid of $\theta$ without keeping the order down. In any case, given your initial conditions, you can still find my initial conditions, as the first equation gives $\ddot{r}$ directly, and combining the two gives $\dddot{r}$.

Comment: Don't mind about realistic case, just in equation that a constant term at right hand might be simplest, wasn't ? I agree that contant torque is truely simplest case. I am sorry that I did not realize that contant force case is so difficult.

Comment: Unfortunately, your solution seems not satify the initial condition. I will try to find proper solution. Anyway, thank you for sharing time on it.